# XML Validation failed, key not found

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, schema, xerces

I have a problem with a XML-Validation.
I get the following error (even if the XPath is absoulte):

> Key 'FK_Key' with value '1' not found for identity constraint of
> element 'KeyExample'.

It is strange if I remove the namespace from my XSD it is working.
Any ideas ?

Updated:
I added a second Element because I want to reference the primary key in more than one element.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Import xmlns="https://www.mycompany.com"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <KeyExample>
        <Keys>
            <Key Id="1"/>
            <Key Id="2"/>
        </Keys>
        <KeyRefs>
            <KeyRef RefId="1"/>
            <KeyRef RefId="2"/>
        </KeyRefs>
        <KeyRefs2>
            <KeyRef2 RefId="1"/>
            <KeyRef2 RefId="2"/>
        </KeyRefs2>
    </KeyExample>
</Import>
```

XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
  targetNamespace="https://www.mycompany.com" xmlns="https://www.mycompany.com">
  <xs:element name="Import">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="KeyExample"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="KeyExample">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="Keys"/>
        <xs:element ref="KeyRefs"/>
        <xs:element ref="KeyRefs2"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:key name="PK_Key">
      <xs:selector xpath=".//Key"/>
      <xs:field xpath="@Id"/>
    </xs:key>
    <xs:keyref name="FK_Key" refer="PK_Key">
      <xs:selector xpath=".//*"/>
      <xs:field xpath="@RefId"/>
    </xs:keyref>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="Keys">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="Key"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="Key">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="Id" use="required" type="xs:integer"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="KeyRefs">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="KeyRef"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="KeyRef">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="RefId" use="required" type="xs:integer"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="KeyRefs2">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="KeyRef2"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="KeyRef2">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="RefId" use="required" type="xs:integer"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I change the xpath from

```
<xs:keyref name="FK_Key" refer="PK_Key">
    <xs:selector xpath=".//*"/>
    <xs:field xpath="@RefId"/>
</xs:keyref>
```

to

```
<xs:keyref name="FK_Key" refer="PK_Key">
    <xs:selector xpath=".//KeyRef"/>
    <xs:field xpath="@RefId"/>
</xs:keyref>
```

it validates your xml example.

Comment: yes, in this case it's working, but in my original xsd I have few more elements with the same attribut and same primay key that's why I use *

Comment: change the xpath expression from xpath="//*" to xpath="//*/RefId" then the above example is working again.

Comment: sorry, not working, it's right that the validation is successful but try to change a RefId to an invalid value that is not listed as primay key. Result => also successful

Comment: Correct I missed that part, I was more focused on getting the example to work. After having a proper look at the content I realized that you have specified a namespace on the xsd. that means you also need to use the namespace in the xpath. by adding xmlns:tns="https://www.mycompany.com" to get a namespace prefix and changing the PK_KEY xpath to <xs:selector xpath="./tns:Keys/tns:Key"/> and the FK_KEY to <xs:selector xpath="./*/*"/> I worked for me.

Comment: hmm and is there a way with a default namespace without prefix ?